# Geemap map center is not in the right place

Tags: google-earth-engine, geemap, google-colab

I try to center map in my location at Java Island. The coordinate is [107.169, -6.661]. But it seems not in the right place. When I load the script, it load to Greenland. I show the wrong result. [image] Java Island to Greenland is very far. It is about 11,550 km. It is the script :

```
import ee
import geemap
Map = geemap.Map(center=[107.169, -6.661], zoom=4)
Map
```

How to get in the right place for Java Island?

Comment: What would be the "right place"? How far does it vary from the coordinates provided? What is the resolution at zoom level 4? Please [Edit] the Question.

Comment: The answer is Map = geemap.Map(center=(-6.5, -252.5), zoom=10). But, I don't know why the number doesn't represent longitude and latitude.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As explained in the [documentation](https://geemap.org/core/#geemap.core.Map), `center` should be latitude and longitude. You're providing longitude and latitude. You'll need to flip them:

```py
Map = geemap.Map(center=[-6.661, 107.169], zoom=4)
```

Comment: ok thank you for your answer